# You've been into the cook's pot

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

In Stephen King's "Salem's Lot" there is following passage (my emphasis):

> Floyd put the paper down. 'Devil worshippers in the Lot? Come on, Dell. **You've been into the cook's pot.**'

What does "to be in the cook's pot" mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I'm almost certain it's not a standard expression / idiom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to watch the whole video to understand the meaning of "keep out of the cook's pot", but perhaps it is worthwhile for readers of Stephen King:

[I met an ancient Irish crone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUVHscgrot4&t=276s) (Youtube video)

In summary, regarding the idiom cited in the question above as used in *Salem's Lot* (which I haven't read, by the way): Judging by the story told in this video, the "cook" is an alchemist / sorcerer who indulges in psychotropic drugs which they find in the wild, in the form of certain herbs and/or mushrooms, etc. They process them by cooking, often. The cook's pot holds the 'potions' which are intended primarily for the cook's own personal use. It is off-limits to everyone without the cook's permission. It is generally off-limits to novices or initiates to the craft, due to the unpredictable nature of the potential effects on the mental condition of anyone who is not accustomed to using it.

(Yes, apparently Stephen King did allude to such a practice, in his book based on a theme of witchcraft.)

Comment: In that case, it's off-topic and shouldn't be given an 'answer'. This doesn't qualify as more than link-only advice in any case. A 'comment' is still the only way to help the OP when their question is clearly off-topic.

Comment: The question asks about an idiom found published in a very popular contemporary novel, by an author who is still living. If that's off-topic, the question will be closed soon enough. However until that happens, I know the answer. And the way that I know it, is through this video I'd watched already (not long ago, in fact). It just happens to illustrate the meaning of the idiom, in the proper context, quite clearly. English language is as much about speech as it is about text.

Comment: There are just over 600 hits on Google for "into the cook's pot" and a flatline for the string on Google Ngrams. That does not signify that this is anywhere near idiom status. It is a one-off usage. And interpretation of poetry, song lyrics, literature ... when there are one-off usages is off-topic. Wrong SE site ('Literature' deals with general interpretations).